# In Magento,how can i add different image for same product that was assigned to more than one category,When it is in different categories

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I Have a product for example,t-shirt that is added to men's category and women's category.Now I want to display a woman's image of that t-shirt on women's category & man's t-shirt image in men's category.

Is there any possiblities for the above without creating the same product again.

If possible kindly provide idea for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok fair enough.  Here's a quick solution to your problem.   It's a bit scrappy, but you get the idea.  In this example I assume your ladies category has an ID of 123, and the image you want to show in the ladies category is the product's second image;

```
$otherImage = false;
$catId = 123; // The id of the category to show a different image on
$imageNumber = 2; // The position in the gallery of the image you want to show

$currentCatId = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory()->getId();

if($currentCatId == $catId) { // This is the category you wanted

$count = 1;
$gallery = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getMediaGalleryImages(); 

foreach ($gallery as $image): 
    if($count == $imageNumber) {
        // This is the image you want
        $otherImage = $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image', $image->getFile())->resize(180); 
    }
    $count++;
endforeach;

}

if($otherImage) { echo '<img src="'.$otherImage.'" />'; } else { echo '<img src="'.$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(180).'" />'; }
```

Comment: While this is probably the better solution, it's risky because remember this product could be in multiple categories. So if this page is bookmarked and returned to in the future you will not be part of a current category and this $currentCatId = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory()->getId(); would return null

Comment: Additionally, how would you handle search? Maybe add two new image attributes and then assign unique images, and then create some type of custom functionality to allow the user to sort by male or female on the list.phtml and view.phtml files.  Maybe add these attribute images to the collection via XML update.   Any thoughts?  I just don't see a real clean Magento way to solve this problem.

Comment: Hi Rob,  the code above would be implemented in catalog/list.phtml, which always returns category Id.   In terms of search, I'd leave that as is (return default image) as who knows what gender the searcher is.  Unless of course they use an advanced search with a gender option, but that's a different story.  I still personally think a unisex main image would be the way to go - or even a picture of the product itself rather than being worn, but that's a whole other discussion:)

Comment: Sorry that didn't read correctly! I meant a category will always return a category Id. If cat id is null, the if statement will simply return false.   I do seem to remember search pages and custom collections using the list template return the Id of the category tree parent category, but I'm not infront of my workstation to confirm that right now. Regarding filtering by gender, that's easy to achieve with a layered attribute, but this is all quite messy.

Comment: Ah,  my fault in misreading the request to have the image only in the category. My mind wandered to think this image would also be used on the product detail page which would return null. Again my misunderstanding. Anyways, I still think your answer is the best solution given the criteria and that there really isnt a clean solution given the situation

Comment: adding it inside the foreach() of collection,its working perfect.thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no native way to do this in Magento.  Product images can be set per store view but not per category.  I can think of various ways you could achieve this, but unless your portfolio is huge, I would recommend you either use a unisex image (maybe both male and female) or create a separate product for each gender.

T

Comment: I cannot create a product again,because the product SKU matters.currently we are using Unisex.But Looking for Yet another way through any code editing.